# How do you pull git committer information for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline set up in groovy and need to pull the person who committed some code in git so I can publish that persons name who broke the build.  I've searched the web and can't seem to find a solution.  I figured out how to publish posted in slack by using the slack plugin for jenkins.  Example:

```
slackSend color: 'warning', message: "${git.user_name} broke the build."
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use shell for that and execute `git` command to retrieve data, store it in a file and later read the file into a variable, like this:

```
sh 'git log --format="%ae" | head -1 > commit-author.txt'                 
readFile('commit-author.txt').trim()
```

The above will give you the last commit author.

Comment: No need to store it in a file, see answer by @AlinSoare

Answer (score 5):

I use the following method.

First add a stage in JenkinsFile to retrieve commit author (and message) from git log into an env. var:

```
stage('get_commit_details') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B ${GIT_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
                env.GIT_AUTHOR = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%cn ${GIT_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in post-build action send the Slack message:
(BTW I send to two different channels (success/failure) so that the success channel can be muted.

```
post {
    failure {
        slackSend (channel: 'xyz-build-failure', color: '#FF0000', message: """FAILED:
Job: ${env.JOB_NAME}
Build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
Build: ${env.BUILD_URL})
Comitted by: ${env.GIT_AUTHOR}
Last commit message: '${env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG}'""")
    }
    success {
        slackSend (channel: 'xyz-build-success', color: '#00FF00', message: """SUCCESS:
Job: ${env.JOB_NAME}
Build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
Build: ${env.BUILD_URL})
Comitted by: ${env.GIT_AUTHOR}
Last commit message: '${env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG}'""")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's another way to pull that information.

For each job run in Jenkins there's a variable which is called `${env.BUILD_URL}`.

If you add to this `${env.BUILD_URL}` "api/json" and curl this url you will get all the information that Jenkins knows about that build.

Committer name is also displayed there:

```
  "commitId": "d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67",
  "timestamp": 1499117423000,
  "author": {
    "absoluteUrl": "https://jenkins.company.com/user/camelel",
    "fullName": "itai ganot"
```

The following command will get you the full name of the last committer:

```
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~/src/scripts -  (master) $ curl -s --insecure  https://jenkins.company.com/job/geek-kb/job/scripts/job/master/5/api/json | python -mjson.tool | grep fullName
                        "fullName": "itai ganot"
```

Example:

```
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~/src/scripts -  (master) $ curl -s --insecure  https://jenkins.company.com/job/geek-kb/job/scripts/job/master/5/api/json
    {"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","actions":[{"_class":"hudson.model.CauseAction","causes":[{"_class":"jenkins.branch.BranchIndexingCause","shortDescription":"Branch indexing"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData","buildsByBranchName":{"master":{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.Build","buildNumber":5,"buildResult":null,"marked":{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","branch":[{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","name":"master"}]},"revision":{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","branch":[{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","name":"master"}]}}},"lastBuiltRevision":{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","branch":[{"SHA1":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","name":"master"}]},"remoteUrls":["https://github.com/geek-kb/scripts.git"],"scmName":""},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.GitTagAction"},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl"},{},{},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"},{},{}],"artifacts":[],"building":false,"description":null,"displayName":"# 5 | master","duration":17807,"estimatedDuration":14531,"executor":null,"fullDisplayName":"Itai Ganot » scripts » master # 5 | master","id":"5","keepLog":false,"number":5,"queueId":4894,"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1499117462714,"url":"https://jenkins.company.com/job/geek-kb/job/scripts/job/master/5/","changeSets":[{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList","items":[{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet","affectedPaths":["Jenkinsfile"],"commitId":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","timestamp":1499117423000,"author":{"absoluteUrl":"https://lel.doesntexist.com/user/camelel","fullName":"itai ganot"},"authorEmail":"camelel@gmail.com","comment":"Test\n","date":"2017-07-04 00:30:23 +0300","id":"d2212180afc238fb423981d91f39d680dfd06c67","msg":"Test","paths":[{"editType":"edit","file":"Jenkinsfile"}]}],"kind":"git"}],"nextBuild":null,"previousBuild":{"number":4,"url":"https://lel.doesntexist.com/job/geek-kb/job/scripts/job/master/4/"}}itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~/src/scripts -  (master) $ curl -s --insecure  https://lel.doesntexist.com/job/geek-kb/job/scripts/job/master/5/api/json
```

For more readability, you may use python jsonTool or the tool `jq` which will order the output as JSON.

```
curl ${env.BUILD_URL}api/json | python -mjson.tool
```

or

```
curl ${env.BUILD_URL}api/json | jq
```

Answer (score 2):

One line:

```
def lastCommiterEmail = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log --format="%ae" | head -1').trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of pulling user email.

```
script{
def COMMITTER_EMAIL = bat (
                script: "git --no-pager show -s --format=%%ae",
                  returnStdout: true
              ).split('\r\n')[2].trim()

    echo "The last commit was written by ${COMMITTER_EMAIL}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get committers if you have Email Ext Plugin installed:

```
def emailTo = emailextrecipients([culprits()])
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can use

```
script
{
   def committerDetails = bat ( 
      script: 'git log -n 1 --format="%%ae"',
      returnStdout: true
   )

   env.COMMITTER_EMAIL = committerDetails.tokenize('\n')[2]
}
```

And use it like

```
mail to: "${env.COMMITTER_EMAIL}",
 from: 'someEmailAddress@email.com',
 subject: 'Buld Failures Detected', 
 body: "Job Failed - \"${env.JOB_NAME}\" build: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n\nView the log at:\n ${env.BUILD_URL}\n\nBlue Ocean:\n${env.RUN_DISPLAY_URL}"
```

If you want all email addresses for all commits on the branch, you can use

```
def allCommitterDetails = bat ( 
 script: 'git log --format="%%ae"',
 returnStdout: true
)

def committersEmails = allCommitterDetails.tokenize('\n')
committersEmails .unique()
env.COMITTERS_EMAILS = committersEmails
```