# Jenkins Environment variable in not working in Slack notification

Tags: jenkins, notifications, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, slack

Configured Slack notification in my Global Slack Messages configuration. I can able to get the Build number, build start date, and Job name from environment variables but cant fetch environment variables like  GIT committer email and the changes affected in that particular build

In Jenkins(Manage Jenkins>>Configure system>>Global Slack Messages)

I have tried to send some deployment information to the slack channel

Build Start Time: ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}

BUILD_NUMBER :${BUILD_NUMBER}

Job Name : ${JOB_NAME}

Committer : ${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL}

${JOB_NAME} Build completed Successfully !!

**And the output in Slack channel**

Job1 #1134 - #1134 Success after 21 min

Build Start Time: 13-03-2023 10:29:56 IST
BUILD_NUMBER :1134
Job Name : Job1
**Committer : ${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL}**

Job1 Build completed Successfully !!

==============================================

Here I can't able to fetch the the committer email and changes that build on that particular build.

And please let me know the environment variable to get the git changes that build on the particular build.

Anyone please help me on this to resolve it.

Comment: might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719267/3730626

Answer (score 0):

`${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL}` is not a native Jenkins variable. It is an environment variable provided by a plugin.

So you have to declare the type of variable that it is, otherwise it just considers it as plain text.
Update to `Committer : ${env.GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL}`